# How to convert a json string to an array of known types using Gson?

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson, deserialization

I have a Request class

```
class Request{
     String serviceName ;
     String methodName;
     Serializable[] arguments;
}
```

This represents a request to execute a specific method on a server.

the arguments is an array of random fully serilizable objects.

Now I serialize it using

```
Request req = new Request("serviceName" , "methodName" , Serializable...) 
// all arguments are specified through the elipsis and stored in the arguments array
Gson gson = new Gson() ;

gson.toJson(request) ;
```

Now I am trying to deserialize - The problem is obvious since Gson doesn't know the types of each element in the array.

So to deserialize I have a

```
Class<?>[] argTypes = new Class<?>[equalNumberToArguments]() ;
// This type array is filled with types that I know match the arguments array in request.
```

Now I have a custom deserializer

```
class RequestDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Request> {

        Class<?>[] paramTypes = null ;

        // The types matching the arguments array are specified through the          constructor here. 
        RequestDeserializer(Class<?>[] types){
            paramTypes = types ;
        }

        @Override
        public Request deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonParseException {

            final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

            String s = jsonObject.get("serviceName").getAsString(); 
            String m = jsonObject.get("methodName").getAsString();
            JsonElement element = jsonObject.get("arguments") ;

            if (element.isJsonArray()){
                JsonArray array = element.getAsJsonArray() ;

                // - how do I implement retrieval of each json object from   
                array here ?
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I am using

```
class RequestDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Request> {

    JsonElement element = null ;
    JsonElement argumentJson = null ;
    Class<?> types = null ;

    public RequestDeserializer(Class<?> tps){
        types = tps ;
    }

    public Object[] getArguments(){

        if (types.length == 0)
            return null ;

        Object[] arguments = new Object[types.length] ;

        if (argumentJson != null && argumentJson.isJsonArray()){

            JsonArray array = argumentJson.getAsJsonArray() ;

            for ( int i=0 ; i < types.length ; i++){

                JsonElement arrayEle = array.get(i) ;

                Gson gson = new Gson() ;

                arguments[i] = gson.fromJson(arrayEle, types[i]) ;
            }
        }
        return arguments;
    }
}
```